# Pass npm config in a different way than .npmrc

Tags: npm

For some reason related to the tools I'm using I can't use `.npmrc` file. There is another way to pass configuration to npm?

Comment: Can you explain _what_ exactly you are trying to do and _why_ you cannot use `npmrc` files? The [npm article on config files](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc) mentions the command line and environment variables as other options for configuration.

Comment: Yes sure. for the sake but the tools are out of the scope of npm and Node. Here the issue that explain my problem https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/394